# Why is $|z^k|=|z|^k$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}, k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

### Why is $|z^k|=|z|^k$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}k\in\mathbb{N}$? How can I prove this easily?

Edit: Using the hints I have for $k=2$

$|(a+ib)(a+ib)|=|a^2+2abi-b^2|=\sqrt{a^4+b^4-2a^2b^2+4a^2b^2}=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(a^2+b^2)}=|z||z|$

OK, now Induction $k\Rightarrow k+1$:

$|z^k|=|z|^k \Rightarrow |z|^{k+1}=|z|^k|z|=|z^k||z|=|z^{k+1}|$

Is this ok?

Comment: Prove that $|wz| = |w||z|$ by explicitly writing $w=a+ib$ and $z= c+id$. Then, induct on $k$.

Answer (score 3):

It follows from induction and the fact that $|zw|=|z|\cdot |w|$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What about using induction on $k$?

Answer (score 1):

$z=re^{iu}$ where $r>0$, $|z|^k=r^k$ and $|z|=r$.